# Flutter Can't create a Listview to fill height but only have fixed width

Tags: flutter, listview

I can't work this out. It should be really simple. (This is Flutter Desktop)

I want a Row with 2 columns. The first column should be full height available but only 200 wide. Column 2 should be full height and use the remainder of the width.

I have tried all sorts but always get an overflow rather than a scrollable list.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the last iteration of my code.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bnode Management'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text('This is the title'),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: piItems.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(width: 40, color: Colors.red, child: Text(piItems[index].id));
                      }),
                ),
              ),
              Container(color: Colors.blue, child: const Text('Column 1')),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `Column` like to have max space, therefor we can use `Expanded` on it instead of using on 1st `Column`. Also, the `Row` is needed to have max height. For this, we will wrap this `Row` with `Expanded`.

```dart
body: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    const Text('This is the title'),
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: piItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                      width: 40,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text(piItems[index].id));
                }),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text('Column 1'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I also prefer using `LayoutBuilder` on body in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at LayoutBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, just mixed some things. Let's go step by step.

1. > I want a Row with 2 columns

Ok, that's just a Row with two children.

```
Row(
  children: [child1, child2],
)
```

2. > The first column should be full height available but only 200 wide.

It would take the full height automatically but I see that in your code example you have a `Column` with `Text` title, so we should wrap our `Row` with `Expanded`. Also, the first Column should take 200 px.

```
Column(
  children: [
    const Text('This is the title'),
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 200,
            child: child1,
          ),
          child2,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

3. > Column 2 should be full height and use the remainder of the width.

So we wrap our 2nd child with `Expanded` inside the `Row`.

```
Column(
  children: [
    const Text('This is the title'),
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 200,
            child: child1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: child2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

The end result based on your code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bnode Management'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text('This is the title'),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 200,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: piItems.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                          width: 40,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text(piItems[index].id));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: const Text('Column 1'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Fabulous explanation, thank you :)

Comment: Do not forget to upvote/mark the answer as correct, then ;)